Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Bitcoin Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Getting an online Litecoin wallet
Net Score: -3 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

Different balances Bitcoin-Qt vs. Blockchain.info
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

Why does the Bitcoin conversion rate change wildly?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

Countrywide Internet isolation, inevitable fork
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

How do I investigate an address or transaction?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

Get the number of confirmations for an external address
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

Are there alternatives to ButterflyLabs?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

How do I use electrum on multiple computers?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

What's next after scrypt?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

gcminer with ATIRADEON HD3600 on ubuntu 12.04 64bit headless won't detect GPU
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


